# Getting page source by Python + Selenium not works, connection refused

Tags: python, selenium

I try to get page source by using Selenium.
My code looks like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://python.org')

html_source = browser.page_source

print html_source
```

When I run the script, it opens browser but nothing happens. When I'm waiting without doing anything it throws "Connection refused", after about 15 seconds.

If I enter the address and go to the website, nothing happens too.

Why doesn't it work? Script looks good in my opinion and it should work

I'm doing it because I need to get page source after JS scripts are executed and I suspect that it can be done by Selenium.

Or maybe you know any other ways to get page source after JavaScript is loaded?

Comment: your code worked for me on Chrome.

Comment: Your code is correct and working fine on my machine , can you put the error message is question. Also is geckodriver placed at proper place?

Comment: Yes geckodriver is on right place. When I'm using chrome driver it returns error: 

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"(E6D48733C6290A309E4C65A77ECAFAB8)","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}

Comment: And when the browser is opened the site address is: "data:,"

Comment: And also browser shows me warning: Unsupported flag was used....:--ignore-certificate-errors

Comment: I changed chrome driver from 2.9 to 2.27 and it works.
But still not works on Firefox. But is there any other way to get page source(with loaded javascripts) without opens browser?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you have invoked `get()` method passing the argument as `https://python.org`. Instead you must have passed the argument as **https://www.python.org/** as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.python.org/')
html_source = browser.page_source
print (html_source)
```

> **Note** : Ensure that you are using the latest **`Selenium-Python v3.8.0`** clients, **`GeckoDriver v0.19.1`** binary along with latest **`Firefox Quantum v57.x`** Web Browser.

Comment: `does not work for me` doesn't throws any light on what happening. Update the question with your current code block & the error stack trace you are seeing.